# Oracle SQL prepareStatement sending NULL as parameter within setXXX()?

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, prepared-statement

Hey all I have the following SQL query:

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT " +
                                                "DECODE(MAX(ID), NULL, 'NO', 'YES') BOOL_VAL " +
                                              "FROM " +
                                                "MASTERNICSDB " + 
                                              "WHERE " + 
                                                "FTAG = ? " +
                                              "AND " + 
                                                "BADGENUM IS ?");
stmt.setString(1, System.getenv("COMPUTERNAME").toUpperCase());
stmt.setNull(2, Types.VARCHAR);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
rs.next();
```

The issue with the above is that it keeps throwing:

> ORA-00908: missing NULL keyword

I have tried all of the following:

```
stmt.setNull(2, Types.VARCHAR);
stmt.setString(2, "NULL");
stmt.setNull(2, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
stmt.setObject(2, null);
```

None of which seem to work. They all get the same error as above.

However, if I place the values inside the query all is fine - but I don't want to do that due to SQL injection and all that fun stuff.

Comment: you can't pass that as a parameter, `IS NULL`  is a single operator.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name then what do you suggest?

Comment: Use `BADGENUM IS NULL` inside your SQL string

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name wouldn't that be prone to an SQL injection?

Comment: How can that be prone to injection if the expression is hardcoded.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32642737/277480

Comment: Your code does not concatenate any user input if it contains the constant string `AND BADGENUM IS NULL`

Comment: Make it the answer so that i can give you credit.